# OK, NOK count of Sonuc column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

```
SELECT COUNT(Sonuc)
      ,CAST(Tarih AS Date)
      ,VardiyaAdi
      ,ReferansNo
      ,MusteriAdi
      ,KontrolEden
FROM   Kayit_MPI_Kontrolu
GROUP BY
       CAST(Tarih AS Date)
      ,VardiyaAdi
      ,ReferansNo
      ,MusteriAdi
      ,KontrolEden
```

I have a query as this. 
I want to get in Sonuc column OK and NOK value count. How can i do it ?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: You should explain what OK and NOK would mean, even if it is the obvious 'OK <=> COUNT > 0'

Comment: OK and NOK is nvarchar value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be like this,

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Sonuc = 'OK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OK
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Sonuc = 'NOK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NOK
      ,CAST(Tarih AS Date)
      ,VardiyaAdi
      ,ReferansNo
      ,MusteriAdi
      ,KontrolEden
FROM   Kayit_MPI_Kontrolu
GROUP BY
       CAST(Tarih AS Date)
      ,VardiyaAdi
      ,ReferansNo
      ,MusteriAdi
      ,KontrolEden
```

Answer (score 1):

```
      select sum( case when Sonuc = 'OK' then 1 else 0 end ) as countOK,
             sum( case when Sonuc = 'NOK' then 1 else 0 end ) as countNOK,
                   ,CAST(Tarih AS Date)
      ,VardiyaAdi
      ,ReferansNo
      ,MusteriAdi
      ,KontrolEden
FROM   Kayit_MPI_Kontrolu
GROUP BY
       CAST(Tarih AS Date)
      ,VardiyaAdi
      ,ReferansNo
      ,MusteriAdi
      ,KontrolEden
```

Comment: Extra `,` is there after second line